# Python Unsupported operator type for & error handling

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do an if statement using rows of a dataframe. Sometimes, the value can be None, and this is what I am wanting to check for.

```
for row in tqdm(df.index):

        add = df.loc[row, "add"]
        name = df.loc[row, "name"]

        if str(add) is not None and str(name) is not None:
            add_name = add + " " + name
        elif str(add) is not None:
            add_name = add
        elif str(name) is not None:
            add_name = name
        add_names.append(add_name)
```

As you can see above, if neither of the values are None, then I want to concatenate. If either is None, then I want to use the other value.

However, I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

I can't figure out how to solve this. I thought by trying to cast to a `str` this would work but sadly not.

EDIT:
This is a sample DF I am testing with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "name": [
                "Random Name",
                "Another Name"
            ],
            "add": [
                None,
                "Pre text"
            ]
        }
    )
```

I am expecting the new field to be:

```
Random Name
Pre text Another Name
```

Comment: there are other better ways to do an ```if statement``` in python/pandas. Would you prefer fixing your code, or changing it to a more 'pythonic' way? Like  ```numpy.where```, and ```numpy.select``` for your example.

Comment: Always open to hearing improvements to my code!

Comment: is it possible to add some sample data so that we can replicate the issue and provide an answer?

Comment: I've added sample data now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "name": [
                "Random Name",
                "Another Name",
                None,
            ],
            "add": [
                None,
                "Pre text",
                'something'
            ]
        }
    )
```

First replace missing values use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html), join by `+` and last add [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) for remove traling whitespaces :

```
df['add_name'] = (df['add'].fillna('') + ' ' + df['name'].fillna('')).str.strip()

print (df)
           name        add               add_name
0   Random Name       None            Random Name
1  Another Name   Pre text  Pre text Another Name
2          None  something              something
```

Another solution in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by empty string if match both masks and join by space or replace missing values by another column:

```
df['add_name'] = np.where(df['add'].notna() & df['name'].notna(), 
                          df['add'].fillna('') + ' ' + df['name'].fillna(''),
                          df['add'].fillna(df['name']))

print (df)
           name        add               add_name
0   Random Name       None            Random Name
1  Another Name   Pre text  Pre text Another Name
2          None  something              something
```

---

If need test more masks, e.g. also misisng values (by invert mask by `~`) is possible use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "name": [
                "Random Name",
                "Another Name",
                None,
                None
            ],
            "add": [
                None,
                "Pre text",
                'something',
                None
            ]
        }
    )

m1 = df['add'].notna()
m2 = df['name'].notna()
    
s1 = df['add'].fillna('') + ' ' + df['name'].fillna('')
s2 = df['add'].fillna(df['name'])

df['add_name'] = np.select([m1 & m2,
                            m1 & ~m2,
                            ~m1 & m2], 
                           [s1, df['add'], df['name']], default=None)

print (df)
           name        add               add_name
0   Random Name       None            Random Name
1  Another Name   Pre text  Pre text Another Name
2          None  something              something
3          None       None                   None
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)**, as the following:

```
import numpy as np

df['Random Name'] = np.where( (df['name'].notnull()) & (df['add'].notnull()),df['name'].astype(str)+ " " + df['add'].astype(str),
                             np.where(df['name'].notnull(),df['name'],df['add']))
```

Which gives:

```
Out[188]: 
           name       add            Random Name
0   Random Name      None            Random Name
1  Another Name  Pre text  Another Name Pre text
```

We are basically checking whether both columns are `notnull`, and putting them together if that's the case, and then checking if individually the columns are null, and returning the other.